# dyld: Symbol not found: _UnityPluginLoad

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to run the xcode project directly exported from Unity. It was successfully built but crashed when running on simulator.

### Build process

I have changed Unity `player setting` -> `simulator sdk`
`Auto Graphics API` -> unchecked, unselected Metal, selected `OpenGLES3` & `OpenGLES2`

I used the Vuforia `Cloud Recognition` function.

### Error

> dyld: Symbol not found: _UnityPluginLoad
>     Referenced from: /Users/xiaoming/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E8DD590D-55EE-4680-8E48-4C537F1DA4DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E836283D-F9C8-4E91-8CDF-545060E3136A/CloudRecoTest.app/CloudRecoTest
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /Users/xiaoming/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E8DD590D-55EE-4680-8E48-4C537F1DA4DA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E836283D-F9C8-4E91-8CDF-545060E3136A/CloudRecoTest.app/CloudRecoTest

### Version

My XCode version is `10.2.1`

My Unity version is `2018.3.8f1`

Comment: got the same problem. did you get any solution?

Comment: @Dungeon no, I ended up running on a real device instead